# How do you pass an SQL script with parameters to a unix script?

Tags: sql, unix, plsql, parameter-passing

So I have a script that takes two arguments, a database schema and a pl sql script with a parameter and am trying to figure out how to include that parameter:

```
unixScript.ksh db_schemaParm sqlScript.sql parmForSqlScript
```

Where do I put parmForSqlScript?

Thank you!

Comment: Your title makes sense, but your question body doesn't.  Is that because I don't understand unix scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it just needs to be in ""

```
unixScript.ksh db_schemaParm "sqlScript.sql parmForSqlScript"
```